# Is there a software that simulates a pen and paper?

Tags: pdf, pdf-viewer, pdf-editor, pdf-generation

My university requires us to scan homework to PDF and send it via the website, and I have a problem using paper because my writing is messy. I saw some students using an iPad or a Chromebook to write directly on a PDF ,using the pen with the device, and it looks so clean and if there is a mistake they can always press Ctrl+Z.
I'm using an Acer Laptop with Windows 10 Home without a touch screen, Is there a software that lets me write PDF files with a mouse that is close a real life pen effect ( I searched online for softwares and there is a lot of options and I can't test them all), other than getting a new device?

Comment: writing or drawing with the mouse is even worse. I don't have too bad handwriting but I always struggle with my mousewriting. You can use a handwriting font and type with the keyboard

Comment: @phuclv I'm gonna be mostly writing math with it, calculus, linear algebra, and discrete math, for a year. My main problem is with tidying and not writing in a straight line..

Comment: Maybe use LaTeX and one of its front-ends (no experience with front-ends).

Comment: You want to buy a graphics tablet. Huion sells really good hardware at a reasonable price. Different categories, best are the ones with buildin screen, so the "kamvas" devices. Can't get more "pen like", actually it _is_ writing with a pen.

Comment: You are looking for a wacom tablet. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hQ79w0ibytg. Details: https://estore.wacom.com/en-US/one-by-wacom-small-ctl472k1a.html

Comment: if you're writing math then it's an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/230282). What you should use is LaTeX

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert on this and I'm not affiliated with the software but I would recommend you use Adobe Acrobat to write on the PDF directly on the digital document. The Adobe reader is free to download use and can be used to annotate like highlighting, putting x marks or checkmarks, adding a line, adding text, a circle or a dot, and of course, signing as if it was a handwritten signature. But if you want to do more freehand writing and free-form drawings around your document, you need to purchase the pro version. The Pencil tool creates free-form drawings, and the Pencil Eraser tool removes the pencil markups. Here are more details from their support page: https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/commenting-pdfs.html

Answer (score 0):

All current versions of [PDF-XChange Editor](https://www.tracker-software.com/product/pdf-xchange-editor) will allow you to do this.

Simply go to the `Comment` menu and select the `Pencil` tool.  There is also an `Eraser` tool for your convenience.

You can customize the toolbars to place those tools on any toolbar of your choosing, or even a brand new custom toolbar.

I have personally used PDF-XChange Editor, and I find the quality of the product to be very high.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [reMarkable](https://remarkable.com/#A_note_taking_system) can be your solution.

- Convert your handwritten notes into text
- All your notes, organized and accessible on all devices
- Take handwritten notes, read, and review documents
- Take notes directly on PDFs
- Paper-like writing and reading
- Integrates with Google Drive and Dropbox
- 2 weeks of battery life
- Subscribe to Connect to access all other features

[Here is the video](https://youtu.be/-9jRLmYv9Cs)

[image]